# Make my Excel parse dates from CSV like everyone else's

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-365

For my work, I regularly open data in Excel 365 that comes to me in a weird CSV format that I can't control. Here's an example:

```
"Call-off","Receiver ext.","Plant","Status","Supplier ext.","UnPt","Line station","Part family","Production No","Sequence no.","Series/Model","Call-Off date","Trig.type","EDI Arrival","No. old","No. new","SubDel.","Receiver ID","Trailer","File-No.","Created","Date Creation","Last change","Timestamp last Update"
"2238575","=""8010""","=""T21""","=""95""","=""18519280E""","=""*""","=""*"""," ","=""0006459842""","=""20191119T039""","=""16716112""","11/20/2019 12:04 AM","=""IB""","11/20/2019 12:00 AM","6443","6444","=""0""","=""MBUSI"""," ","43889667","=""AMSSTIN""","11/20/2019 12:07:54 AM","=""SSTIFILE""","11/20/2019 12:07:54 AM"
"2238574","=""8010""","=""T21""","=""90""","=""18519280E""","=""*""","=""*"""," ","=""0006459842""","=""20191119T039""","=""16716112""","11/20/2019 12:04 AM","=""IB""","11/20/2019 12:00 AM","6442","6443","=""0""","=""MBUSI"""," ","43889666","=""AMSSTIN""","11/20/2019 12:07:54 AM","=""SSTIFILE""","11/20/2019 12:07:54 AM"
"2238572","=""510898""","=""456""","=""90""","=""33265005""","=""56""","=""BROADCAST"""," ","=""0006459842""","=""300000162834""","=""167""","11/20/2019 12:04 AM","=""SMP""","11/20/2019 12:00 AM","56386","56387","=""0""","=""SMP"""," ","43889664","=""AMSSTIN""","11/20/2019 12:07:53 AM","=""SSTIFILE""","11/20/2019 12:07:53 AM"
```

[An example Excel file is here.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aighv3zT9T9UgTPo9VdoKdUK0RNP?e=G9t5Nk)

I need to add formulas that operate with the dates and times in the data (see the last column in the example data). The trouble is, my Excel sees the dates as strings. This leads me to insert a table then do Data -> From table/range which opens up a new sheet with the fake formulas removed leaving only values (and destroying numbers with leading zeroes). My other alternative is to insert a helper column and parse the date out of the date string.

The thing is, whenever my colleagues do the same as I do, following the instructions I've written, they get their dates as proper dates. This is operating on the same data. And weirder, I've had this issue on two separate machines, but I've never seen my colleagues experience it.

This leads me to believe that there must be some setting somewhere in Excel that's changing things for me. **How can I make my Excel work like my colleagues'?**

*NOTE: I'm not asking how to work around this problem as I already know how to do that. I'm asking why it's happening in the first place and/or how I can prevent it from happening without resorting to workarounds.*

Comment: Make sure the column in which the dates are being placed is not formatted as text but general before importing the data.

Comment: The formatting is all handled by Excel before I even have a chance to do anything. The data app I use downloads a CSV file then opens it in Excel. However it opens is however it opens. Nothing I can do unless there's some setting I can change.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your CSV data.  Could it be that your Windows Regional Settings are `DMY` and your colleagues as `MDY`?  If that is the case, the dates in your example would be interpreted as text (and dates that are NOT interpreted as text would be incorrect.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Yes, it turns out that any time I want to import data from CSV, I have to set my Windows date format to the format of the CSV file--and I routinely deal with data from a variety of countries using a variety of date formats. Could Excel have come up with a worse way of handling this?

Comment: If you import, you can avoid that issue, and all your dates will be handled correctly.

Comment: If only it were that simple! The software I'm stuck with downloads a CSV file to `%temp%` with a random name, then opens it in Excel. There's no way to change this, other than closing the file and manually importing it, finding the file by modification time or something.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Be careful that with your accepted solution that all the dates are being properly translated.  Dates that do not appear as strings are ambiguous, and may be interpreted incorrectly. eg `3/1/2019` might really be `1-Mar-2019` but your system, with the wrong regional date settings, might parse it into  `3-Jan-2019`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Thanks for the reminder. Naturally since I had to set my regional settings to the same as my most common CSV data, I've set them to the same format. Of course, the craziness is that in cases where Excel can't unambiguously work out what date is meant, it should ask the user instead of guessing. 3/1/2019 is ambiguous; 2019-03-01 isn't, which is why it should be the default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Downvoters: Aren't you ashamed?)

To convert a column to format Date:

- Select the column (hover over the header and click when the down-arrow appears)
- In the Home tab, click *Format > Format Cells ...*
- In the dialog, tab Number, select "Date" and set "Locale" to
  "English (United States)"
- Click OK.

The column should now be of type Date.

If you wish to verify that, use in an empty cell the formula
`=VALUE(AS2)`
and drag-extend it over the entire column.

**What I have discovered:**

The Excel documentation is misleading, if not wrong.
The date format of the cell apparently only serves for display.
Excel will parse the strings using operating system functions,
so it is crucial to have the right date format **in Windows**.

In *Control Panel > Region*, tab Formats, I have set "Format:" to
"English (United States)". Without this setting, Excel wouldn't accept
American-type dates.

I have selected the entire column, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
to enter the dialog of "Format Cells", tab Number, and set the format
to "Custom", with the value of `[$-en-US]m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM`.

That was enough for the column AU that I added with the function of
`=VALUE(AS2)` to now correctly analyze the AS column as numeric, giving a
date-time numerical value:

[image]

Another idiosyncrasy of Excel is that, although now numeric, the cells stay
left-justified. If one double-clicks inside one cell, then clicks out,
the cell will suddenly display as right-justified. Go figure.

Comment: This doesn't work and it doesn't answer the question. Formatting a column as a date doesn't coerce strings to dates; it only formats numbers. My dates are being seen as strings. Secondly, I can already manually address the issue. My question is why I'm having this problem while nobody else is.

Comment: My good fellow: Downvoting an answer that works for everyone but not for you isn't really the best tactic. A better move would have been to post an example of your spreadsheet file, and with the proof that it doesn't work, because it must absolutely work unless something very funny is involved. Downvoting doesn't really motivate a person to help.

Comment: My apologies for the downvote; I voted in haste. Unfortunately my vote is now locked in. I posted an example above. I explained that on my machine dates were being seen as strings (when I hit "Evaluate formula" I see double quotes around my dates and errors popping up when I try to do calculations with them). Of course, formatting cells only applies number formatting to numbers, not to strings (is it "text" in Excel speak?). In my example, you can see that the original CSV has dates in double quotes, so one might argue that what I'm seeing is correct. But others don't have the same issue.

Comment: The vote is no longer locked-in (I edited the answer trivially). Also, before answering, I tried to recreate your data and it worked for me. There is something funny in the data you are receiving, which might not show up when posting here. That's why I thought that a real example file is required.

Comment: I've removed my downvote. I don't know who the other downvoter is. I've added a link to an Excel file. Since you've tried to recreate my issue and came up with nothing, welcome to my world! My problem seems unique to me.

Comment: I think I have duplicated your problem. You are doing everything right, my answer is right, all according to the doc. It's Excel that is doing it wrong - date-time seems to be very buggy. I will be trying some workarounds this weekend, if I can find one that works.

Comment: I think I succeeded with your spreadsheet. Try my updated answer on your side.

Comment: Bingo! You nailed it. I had my date settings changed to how I want to see dates. Sille me to think that I can format dates how I wish! Thank you very much! +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in AU2 to convert AS2 to a date;

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(AS2,4,2)&"/"&MID(AS2,1,2)&"/"&MID(AS2,7,4))
```

It happens because the date is in a non-US format. The source data needs to be changed.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I'm not looking to workaround the problem; I already know how to do that. I'm looking for why it happens only to me. harrymc has provided the answer.

Comment: @ScottSeverance I have stated why it happens as well and what you need to do.

Comment: Except it's incorrect. The date is in the US format. My machine was configured to use ISO format. And as I stated above, the source data is out of my control; I can't change it.

Comment: @ScottSeverance How are you accessing the file through desktop Excel or through Excel 365 online via OneDrive or Sharepoint?

Comment: Through desktop Excel.